# Gunzip alternative to tar command

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, centos

A straight-forward question:

Could you please guys give me an alternative to this tar command, using gunzip ?

```
tar -C /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods -xzf custom_opt_mod-mod_geoip.tar.gz
```

I want this because when I am trying to run that command I get with this:

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Thanks

Comment: That command *is* using `gzip`/`gunzip`. That's what the `-z` flag is doing and what the `.gz` on the input filename is indicating. What is your real question? (Also note that `gzip` only operates on single files.)

Comment: `gunzip` doesn't do everything that the `tar` command does. In fact, `tar` calls `gunzip to first unzip the `tar.gz` file, then `tar` extracts that file, which is in `tar` format. So `gunzip` is not *direct alternative*.

Comment: Are you sure that file is gzipped? What does `file custom_opt_mod-mod_geoip.tar.gz` say about it? Try leaving off the `-z` and see if it works. GNU tar can auto-detect gzipped files on its own anyway for extraction so you don't need it.

Comment: If `tar` is saying it's not in `gzip` format, then `gunzip` is not going to help you. It expects `gzip` format! Check the source of your file and find out what you have.

Comment: I was following [this](http://www.servernoobs.com/how-to-install-mod_geoip-on-a-whmcpanel-server/) tutorial and at step 3 I received that error. @Etan: HTML document text. That's what the command says. The wget didn't work well, right ?

Comment: Yeah, that `wget` failed. Try the link manually and you'll see why.

Comment: There's nothing. Dohh. Silly me. Thanks for that file command though. I didn't know it. I'm gonna find another link. Will update the question if anything will go wrong